# Making an .htaccess with multiple wildcard exceptions?

Tags: .htaccess, exception, web, wildcard

I'd like to have all references to my site redirect to `blah.mysite.com`.

I need these specific sub-directories to be directly accessible without a redirect:
`mysite.com/foo`, `mysite.com/bar`, `www.mysite.com/foo`, and `www.mysite.com/bar`

Here is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#Redirect all non-foobar sites to blah
rewritecond %{http_host} .
rewritecond %{http_host} !^(www|.)mysite\.com//foo//
rewritecond %{http_host} !^(www|.)mysite\.com//bar//
rewriterule (.*)$ http://blah.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong.  Can do you have any insights as to how I can fix this?  I've been searching all morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !blah.mysite.com [NC]
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foo|bar)/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://blah.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!  What would I need to do to also exclude items within the `foo` directory from the wildcard?

Comment: @DanCarew put another `.htaccess` with similar rules. in `foo` directory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that will work.  Currently, `mysite.com/foo/image.jpg` will redirect to `http://blah.mysite.com/`.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Found the fix.  I replaced the `/?` in the second line with `(.*)`.  Thanks, again.